# Crashed dual boot system after deleting an almost empty sdc partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I had an Ubuntu live usb that wasn't being formatted back properly through nautilus. I decided to use gparted, and saw what I know now was a necessary partition(?) it had 4kb and three partitions from what I remember, and I deleted it. On rebooting, my Ubuntu didn't boot but loaded up emergency mode. At this point windows was working just fine and all partitions could be mounted and have data.

I found boot-repair/testdisk would be my best options, so I installed my live usb with those. On using boot-repair, my grub developed a lot more entries but windows was working. I decided to go the testdisk route, basically duplicating what I saw on fdisk -l to write new partitions. Ubuntu not yet working.
[Boot repair output here.](https://pastebin.com/z5m4kDKi)

I used boot-repair one last time with filesystem fix flags and now both OS are gone. [This is that output.](https://pastebin.com/PxtEu0E9) The windows recovery partition is also inaccessible now. I can still mount all partitions, so I would like to know how to backup my OS and Storage, preserving configurations in case I need a reinstall. I also have a Windows image backup.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=66b76612-26d5-4e2f-b86d-eaaca44d330f /               ext4      errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=94FD-DAE8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=e60a1c4d-5f36-4b7a-a115-cf27b53e50c0 none            swap    sw              0       0
PARTUUID=40a863e7-01     /media/mystick   auto    rw,user,auto    0    0
UUID=94FD-DAE8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1<>
```

the last is just an annoying hard disk. current partition

```
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047   2048000  1000M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527    532480   260M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3     2582528    4630527   2048000  1000M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4     4630528    4892671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     4892672  944912383 940019712 448.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   944912384 1150683135 205770752  98.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1150683136 1158879215   8196080   3.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda8  1158879232 1928108031 769228800 366.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9  1928110080 1953523711  25413632  12.1G Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: what haopens when you choose ubuntu? 4kb or 4 GB?

Comment: that wasn't a normal partition, so I though it was the usb

Comment: ubuntu boots into emergency mode and has systemd login problems, the partitions are all fine size wise.

Comment: sounds like you deleted a partition that was in etc/fstab ... the swap maybe?  can you post your current directory structure and the contents of etc/fstab

Comment: how does one view that through the live usb?

Comment: liveusb should have gparted for directory structure, and showing mount points. the partitoin that mounts as / is the one you want to look in for fstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these two lines from etc/fstab:

```
PARTUUID=40a863e7-01     /media/mystick   auto    rw,user,auto    0    0
UUID=94FD-DAE8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1<>
```

Uncomment this line (REMOVE THE #):

```
#UUID=94FD-DAE8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

swap was on sda10, now it is sda7, comment out this line:

```
UUID=e60a1c4d-5f36-4b7a-a115-cf27b53e50c0 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And put under it:

```
/dev/sda7   none   swap   sw   0   0
```

if that gets you in then do:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

then change etc/fstab back to uuid identification of swap

Comment: no change unfortunately.

Comment: do you see the error it gives?

Comment: boot is still failing in the same way, to emergency mode, i'd paste journal ctx if I knew how, would that help?

Comment: in grub press "e" to edit  change "quite splash" to "nosplash" watch the output for a failure, it should be on the screen. maybe 10 lines before the crash

Comment: Failed to activate swap swap partition.

Comment: It rebooted again and I just managed to login. Thank you so much! Any ideas on how to fix windows? And would you mind explaining what it was that went wrong?

Comment: see my answer I updated. run those two commands before you log off.

Comment: something you did changed fstab so it was trying to mount drives incorrectly, a missing drive that is in fstab will cause a failed boot. I suspect the change is swap partition identifier  ( sda10 to sda7)

Comment: windows doesn't work on any of it's multiple entries

Comment: you updated grub?  what do you get from windows?

Comment: Yes, it says a required device isn't connected or can't accessed. Error code: 0xc0000225, says it needs installation media

Comment: you have a windows repair disk? you may need to use windows to repair it's boot.... note: this will probably knock grub off does your system allow OS boot so you can choose grub?

Comment: System allows OS boot but I don't have an installation disk. I'd been trusting in recovery partition, but it's windows. I'll look around, Ubuntu is my primary OS so I'm not in a hurry

Comment: you could try copying the windows folder from sda3 to sda2,  it looks like a back up. might get you something. when you get both boot right of of sda2 you can delete sda3 unless you want to keep a back up.  just turn the ESP flag off on it